How can multiple NGINX pods in Kubernetes write logging into their own separate files?
I have an NGINX installation (used as a web proxy) inside a built Docker image in Kubernetes that will eventually have to be upgraded to run multiple pods to handle the traffic volume.
The log output from access.log and error.log needs to not only go into files (for our log collector service) but also appear in the Kubernetes logs, i.e. appear in /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr. My current solution is to run tail -F access.log >> /dev/stdout & and similarly for the error log.
I would like to have these files in a shared PVC storage (so the logs remain after the pod crashes or restarts), and this should work fine as long as I only have one pod.
Once I have multiple pods, I have the problem that all pods will want to write into the same files - access.log and error.log.
I have tried a few things, but it doesn't look like NGINX supports using a variable in the log paths, so I am stuck in writing to static paths.
My best theoretical solution so far is to update the error and access log formats to include the pod name, but that would again involve adding a variable into NGINX, and I'm not sure it would allow that.
I also tried symlinks (ln -sf access-${PODNAME}.log access.log and similar), but this can't work in a multi-pod situation, either, since all pods share the same configuration.
I'm sure I'm not the only one with this situation.
Any ideas I can try?
Thanks!

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

@Jonas Thanks, I totally didn't think of that... Doing it now!

The Kubernetes logging setup is pretty standardized.  Can your log collector collect the container logs on its own, and then you can skip creating the second file-based copy of the logs?

@DavidMaze Unfortunately, our company's log collector of choice needs files.

Someone on serverfault.com had the answer:
In short, just create a copy of the nginx.conf file in the entrypoint script, replace the original log file paths with new ones that include the pod name, then use the edited config file.
Details can be found here:
https://serverfault.com/a/1160501/258134
